# 正規表現[-]?の[]の意味

Tags: ruby, 正規表現

正規表現(Ruby)で

```
^ISBN[-]?[¥d|-]+
```

の場合

```
^ISBN-?[¥d|-]+
```

でも同じ結果になると思うのですが
この場合の`[]`って、`[]`内に指定された文字のどれかにマッチするの意味の`[]`でクラスとかの`[]`とはまた違いますよね

Comment: クラスというのは [Ruby マニュアル](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/spec=2fregexp.html)で言うところの「文字クラス」のことでしょうか？ `[a-z]` のような使い方をするハイフンとは別か、というご質問ですよね。

Comment: 文字クラスのことです。a-zのようなハイフンとは別かという質問であってます

Answer (score 5):

はい、Ruby の正規表現 `[-]` は `-` 1文字にマッチする表現であり、正規表現 `-` と同等です。

Ruby 2.5 のドキュメント ([これ](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/spec=2fregexp.html)や[これ](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/regexp_rdoc.html)) に明示的に書かれているわけではありませんが、`[ ]` の中のハイフンは `[a-z]` のように範囲を表すときのみメタ文字として扱われます。先頭にあるときなど、範囲を表さないときはバックスラッシュによるエスケープ無しでも非メタ文字として扱われます。

たとえば `[-abc]` という正規表現は、`-`, `a`, `b`, `c` にマッチします (実行例: [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/x1Zt59ULZy) / [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jrOb0pT4Kk6UszvV))。

参考ブログ: [正規表現: 文字クラス [ ] 内でエスケープしなくてもよい記号](https://techracho.bpsinc.jp/hachi8833/2017_05_30/40673) -- Tech Racho

Comment: 返信遅れまして申し訳ありません
回答ありがとうございます

やっぱり同じなんですね
すっきりしました
ありがとうございます